# Is there a way to localize Off[some::message]?

Tags: scoping, message-coding

Is there a way to *temporarily* suppress certain messages, so that I could write for example (with made-up syntax for that feature):

```
WithOff[Pattern::patv, rule = (f[x_Integer|{x__Integer}] :> g[x])];
rule2 = x_[x__] :> x;
```

and get no `Pattern::patv` message for `rule`, but do get one for `rule2` iff the message was enabled at the beginning (that is, `WithOff` doesn't affect the on/off status of the message outside of its argument)?

Comment: Why can't you use `Quiet[]`? `Quiet[rule = (f[x_Integer | {x__Integer}] :> g[x]), Pattern::patv]`

Comment: @J.M.: Because I didn't know that and obviously my search-fu was lacking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I agree completely with J.M., `Quiet` is the answer.

Implementing `WithOff` using `Quiet` is (as I'm sure you know) trivial. Here it is, just for fun:

```
ClearAll[WithOff]
SetAttributes[WithOff, HoldAll];
WithOff[msg_, expr_] := Quiet[expr, {msg}];
WithOff[Pattern::patv, rule = (f[x_Integer | {x__Integer}] :> g[x])];
rule2 = x_[x__] :> x;
```

Answer (score 12):

You can define the function:

```
 messageIsOn[msg_]:=Head[msg]===String
```

Which yields True if the message is on. Then do e.g:

```
msgStatus=messageIsOn[Pattern::patv]
If[msgStatus, Off[Pattern::patv]]
< some calculation suppressing message Pattern::patv >
(* Restore the message status *)
If[msgStatus, On[Pattern::patv]]
```

Comment: That's a very interesting solution. While `Quiet` is obviously the thing I've been looking for, this answer is actually the more interesting. I've never considered that `Off` might modify the message itself. Interestingly, assignment can be used to switch the message off, but not to switch it on.

Comment: @celtschk I use this mainly in packages, where I don't want to suppress all messages, but only those I know to be harmless in this case.